# Django rest framework AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_extra_actions'

Tags: python, django

here is urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

from api import views
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('catalogs',views.CatalogView,'catalog')
router.register('companies',views.CompanyView)
router.register('users',views.UserView)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', include(router.urls)),
]
```

here is the errors:

```
    Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7ff9fc5b6848>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/wishbook/Desktop/Dev/rest/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/wishbook/Desktop/Dev/rest/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 124, in inner_run
        self.check(display_num_errors=True)
      File "/home/wishbook/Desktop/Dev/rest/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 359, in check
        include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
      File "/home/wishbook/Desktop/Dev/rest/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
        return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
      File "/home/wishbook/Desktop/Dev/rest/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
        new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
      File "/home/wishbook/Desktop/Dev/rest/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config
        return check_resolver(resolver)
      File "/home/wishbook/Desktop/Dev/rest/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
        return check_method()
      File "/home/wishbook/Desktop/Dev/rest/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 256, in check
        for pattern in self.url_patterns:
      File "/home/wishbook/Desktop/Dev/rest/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
        res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
      File "/home/wishbook/Desktop/Dev/rest/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 407, in url_patterns
        patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
      File "/home/wishbook/Desktop/Dev/rest/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
        res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
      File "/home/wishbook/Desktop/Dev/rest/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 400, in urlconf_module
        return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
        __import__(name)
      File "/home/wishbook/Desktop/Dev/rest/settings/urls.py", line 16, in <module>
        url(r'', include(router.urls)),
      File "/home/wishbook/Desktop/Dev/rest/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/routers.py", line 101, in urls
        self._urls = self.get_urls()
      File "/home/wishbook/Desktop/Dev/rest/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/routers.py", line 363, in get_urls
        urls = super(DefaultRouter, self).get_urls()
      File "/home/wishbook/Desktop/Dev/rest/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/routers.py", line 261, in get_urls
        routes = self.get_routes(viewset)
      File "/home/wishbook/Desktop/Dev/rest/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/routers.py", line 176, in get_routes
        extra_actions = viewset.get_extra_actions()
    AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_extra_actions'
```

here is my serializers.py

```
class CatalogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # company_details = CompanyData(many=True)
    total_pieces = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    total_price = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    # company = CompanySerializer(source='company_name', read_only=True)
    # company_name = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Catalog
        fields = ('name','no_of_pcs','per_piece_price','company_name','total_pieces','total_price')
        #depth = 1

        def to_representation(self, instance):
            rep = super(CatalogSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
            rep['company'] = {
                                  "company_name":instance.company_name.name,
                                  "phone_number":instance.company_name.phone_number,
                                  "company_id":instance.company_name.id
                             }
            return rep

        def get_total_pieces(self, obj):
            totalpieces = Catalog.objects.aggregate(total_pieces=Count('no_of_pcs'))
            return totalpieces["total_pieces"]

        def get_total_price(self, obj):
            totalprice = Catalog.objects.aggregate(total_price=Sum('per_piece_price'))
            return totalprice["total_price"]
```

here is my views.py

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def CatalogView(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        catalogs = Catalog.objects.select_related('company_name')
        serializer = CatalogSerializer(catalogs, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = SnippetSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Django rest framework
Why it is showing:

> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_extra_actions' error.

Why it is showing:

> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_extra_actions' error.

Please check it.
Thanks...

Comment: The problem is in your urls, you need to show those.

Comment: may be this is `@api_view` but it is included into router as `ViewSet`?

Comment: i have shared my urls.py .. please have a look

Comment: As Chiefir says, the problem is you have defined a single view - CatalogView - and are attempting to include it in a router. Why are you doing that? Are CompanyView and UserView also just views? Routers are for viewsets.

Comment: yes. that works but, it is not showing input fields for post..

Comment: i wants to post data also